# Why would an "articles" table (with no relationship to any other table) have a primary key?

Tags: primary-key, relational-theory

Let's say that I have an `articles` table that have two columns: `title` and `content`, and let's say that this `articles` table don't have any relationship with any other table.

Why would this `articles` table have a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

The [purpose of a Primary Key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.ASP) on a table is to ensure uniqueness of the rows in that table by the column(s) defined in the Primary Key. It does not need to be concerned with being part of a relationship with other tables.

Let's say the Primary Key of your example `articles` table is defined on the `title` column. This would guarantee that no two rows in the `articles` table could have the same exact `title` (because of the unique constraint that a Primary Key enforces).

Additionally, some database systems will automatically cluster the table on the column(s) defined in the Primary Key, typically known as a clustered index. This logically sorts the data by those fields, which can lead to improved query efficiency, especially when filtering or trying to sort the results by that field.